# merge two views

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two views A and B both with the same columns names `StudentID, FeeToBePaid, AmountPaid`. In both views `StudentID` is the same. But columns `FeeToBePaid` and `AmountPaid` are different.

I want to replace rows from B with rows from A `if A.FeeToBePaid <= A.AmountPaid` with same `studentID`.

View A

```
SchoolStudentID     sFeeToBePaid     amountpaid
12-S-3003             1000.00         1000.00
```

View B

```
SchoolStudentID   sFeeToBePaid   amountpaid
  12-S-3003         1000.00        0.00 
  11-F-2019         NULL           1000.00
  12-S-3009         NULL           1000.00
```

i need the answer to be

`SchoolStudentID`   `sFeeToBePaid`   `amountpaid`

```
  12-S-3003         1000.00        1000.00
  11-F-2019         NULL           1000.00
  12-S-3009         NULL           1000.00
```

Comment: Those are views or tables? Consider adding a tag to specify wich RDBMS are you using. Also post any query you have tried.

Comment: Is StudentID unique in both views? Do both views contain the same students?

Comment: yes StudentId is Unique for these views. yes both views contain the same students

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you need. If these are views indeed and you want to **physycally** replace the values then what you want to achieve should be done directly with the tables that both views rely on. It can be done also with the views even if they are derived from multiple tables, but be aware that only one of the underlying tables can be modified on each statement. The different answers you have until now are perfectly good but will return a set of values, they will not **physycally** replace any row on your views.

Comment: @Yaroslav These are result of two views.Actually these views are from two different table of which i need to get `feetobepaid` and `feepaid` column as in question. hope you can help.

Comment: How is the data in ViewB ordered?

Answer (score 2):

Try it by combining the results of two `LEFT JOIN` using `UNION` without *ALL* to eliminate duplicate records.

```
SELECT a.SchoolStudentID , 
       CASE WHEN a.sFeeToBePaid  <= a.amountpaid 
            THEN a.sFeeToBePaid 
            ELSE b. sFeeToBePaid 
       END AS sFeeToBePaid,
       CASE WHEN a.sFeeToBePaid  <= a.amountpaid 
            THEN a.amountpaid
            ELSE b.amountpaid 
       END AS amountpaid 
FROM   ViewA a
       LEFT JOIN ViewB b
        ON a.SchoolStudentID  = b.SchoolStudentID 
UNION
SELECT a.SchoolStudentID , 
       CASE WHEN b.sFeeToBePaid  <= b.amountpaid 
            THEN b.sFeeToBePaid 
            ELSE a. sFeeToBePaid 
       END AS sFeeToBePaid,
       CASE WHEN b.sFeeToBePaid  <= b.amountpaid 
            THEN b.amountpaid
            ELSE a.amountpaid 
       END AS amountpaid 
FROM   ViewB a
       LEFT JOIN ViewA b
        ON a.SchoolStudentID  = b.SchoolStudentID
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/83321/4)

Comment: Your are using 4 `CASE` statements instead of two `WHERE` clauses, this means that the query processor will have to do lots of extra work , which then gets discarded in the `UNION`. If you use `WHERE` conditions the query processor can limit its work and you'll know there are no duplicates in the result set so you can use `UNION ALL` to avoid the duplicate checking.

Comment: On consideration, my point is moot. No union is actually necessary. See my edited answer.

Comment: In the second part of your query you alias `ViewA` to `b` and `ViewB` to `a`, this seems unnecessaerily confusing.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

On consideration, any `UNION` is unnecessaery, the following should suffice

```
SELECT
            B.SchoolStudentID
          , CASE WHEN(A.sFeeToBePaid <= A.amountpaid)
                THEN A.sFeeToBePaid
                ELSE B.sFeeToBePaid
            END sFeeToBePaid
          , CASE WHEN(A.sFeeToBePaid <= A.amountpaid)
                THEN A.amountpaid
                ELSE B.amountpaid
            END amountpaid                               
    FROM
          B
        LEFT JOIN
          A ON A.SchoolStudentID = B.SchoolStudentID
```

### [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/41766/7/0)

This just replaces the `B` values with `A` values if the condition is met.

---

**EDIT2**

Adding

```
    ORDER BY
              sFeeToBePaid DESC
            , SchoolStudentID
```

would give you the order you want in this specific case. However, this doesn't seem sensible. I would need to know the desired order of rows in `B` to keep the ordering consistent.

Note, that if no `ORDER BY` is specified the query engine will statisfy the request with what ever order it sees fit. This may often be consistent between calls but, this is just accidental. You'll notice frequent variation if your server has multiple processors and the query performance benefits from using more than one of them. i.e. if your query plan involves parallelization.

Comment: @sharad, so you have a problem with the order, you want the rows with substituted values to come first?

Comment: No i dont want to substitute the value which come first. i was to substitute the row of view B with row of view A with same `schoolstudentid`

Comment: Okay, with SQL server, the order is indetterminate unless you specify it. What order is `B` in? If you do `SELECT * FROM X` the records may not be in the same order from call to call.

Comment: @sharad, is my answer helpful in anyway?